# ionic 4, how go from Livereload to build?

Tags: ionic-framework, livereload

I'm using Livereload to program and test my app, but every time I try to build an app keeps building the Livereload version, how I can build the non-livereload version? I'm new using Livereload and I'm stuck on that

Comment: remove -l tag stop live reload

Comment: I did it, but still compile the live version

Comment: try production build